# Difference between dates in Python and print as 00:00:00

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a string for a date that I convert to datetime and I want to print the time difference between this date (in utc) and the current time in utc. ie. if it's 1 day and 5 hours ahead, print "01:05:00". Or if it's 6 minutes ahead, print "00:00:06". If the date is in the past, then prepend "-", like "-00:00:06".

So far I have a pretty bad solution that prints something like "0:0:27" if it's 27 minutes away and "-2:-5:-46" if it's 2 days in the past. I would like to have a consistent formatting of xx:xx:xx every time. I've looked at many questions and not even sure if i need to use relativedelta or just datetime.timedelta. Any suggestions?

```
for ticket in json.loads(data):
    ticket_rdate = ticket["time_string"]
    if ticket_rdate:
        ticket_rdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(ticket_rdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        difference = relativedelta(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), ticket_rdate)
        ticket["time_until"] = str(difference.days * -1) + ":" + str(difference.hours * -1) + ":" + str(difference.minutes * -1) + ""
    sorted_tickets.append(ticket)
return sorted_tickets
```

This is in python 3.

Comment: I would _not_ read `01:05:00` as "one day and five hours" but "one hour and five minutes". Also, note that some (NASA?) use "-" for times in the future ("countdown T minus 10 seconds...")

Answer (score 0):

If you just do

```
difference = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() -  ticket_rdate)
str(difference)
```

you'll get the output in a consistent format. You can do some string formatting after that to get that in the format that you mentioned.

Comment: OP wants an output in the format `DD:HH:MM`. Your solution doesn’t match this format. This is what I get for a 1m41s difference: `0:01:41.917627`. It should be `00:00:01`.

Answer (score 0):

Use string's format method which will let you specify zero padding. Like:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
diff = utcnow - ticket_rdate

negative = '-' if ticket_rdate < utcnow else ''
hours = int(diff.total_seconds() / 3600)
mins = int(diff.total_seconds() / 60)
ticket['time_until'] = '{}{}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(negative, diff.days, hours, mins)
```

Also, the reason to use relativedelta over timedelta is if you want more flexibility.  relativedelta will let you work with other units like months and years, and provides better support for negative deltas.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454

Comment: Hm I still get ":00:-2" as a result for some.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I think it is correct now using just timedelta.  If you want to show partial minutes, remove the int function around mins.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're limiting the precision to days, I'd say you don't really need to use relativedelta. If you wanted weeks or months, sure, but you don't.

So keeping that in mind in Py3 you can just do something like:

```
delta = time1 - time2
delta = delta // timedelta(minutes=1)
print(str(delta))
```

And let the provided functions do the heavy lifting.

Comment: What does this return? A single integer?

Comment: The //? It's just to throw away seconds/miliseconds from the result.